# Building a System that "fills" horizontal lines with divs and if full continue to next line || Html, Css, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a Stream deck clone but digital using Rust and the Frontend stuff. The Backend works no problem.

I'd like to have something like a list and there are devs that represent the diffrent functionalities. If you add one it will be appended to this list. The webpage fills line to line and creates new lines if needed how would i do this?

Design i made in [Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO5Rs.png)

Do i have to use something like a Grid? Or implement a Horizontal List and create new ones if line is full?

Comment: i mean divs not devs

Comment: [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) should do the trick

Comment: Css-grid would be be optimal here.

Comment: Please use flexbox to build the desired results. Here is the detail of how flexbox css work. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for that.

something like

```
    .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

Will do the trick

[Here](https://codepen.io/Altho/pen/MWBbgYm) is an example I made on codepen